# Spring RestTemplate isn't mapping a 401 to a HttpClientErrorException

Tags: java, spring

Running Spring `4.2.6.RELEASE`, we are experiencing unexpected behavior with fairly typical `RestTemplate` usage; a 401 error is not being translated to a `HttpClientErrorException`.

Specifically, when we receive an expected 401 from the server, we receive a `ResourceAccessException` wrapping an `IOException` with the message `Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ...`, which is raised deep within the bowels of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`.

Our template is configured more or less like so:

```
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // connections per route is not a meaningful limit for us, so set very high
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10000);
    poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Our usage of the client looks like:

```
protected <T, U> ResponseEntity<T> request(UserClientAccount account, U body, String url, HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                           ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType, boolean retry) {
    try {
        HttpEntity<U> request = createHttpEntity(body, account.getToken(this));
        return getRestTemplate().exchange(url, httpMethod, request, responseType, new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                if (retry) {
                    log.warn("Unauthorized response for {}. Refreshing token to retry...", url);
                    refreshToken(account);
                    // tries again
                    return request(account, null, url, httpMethod, responseType, false);
                }
                else {
                    log.error("Unauthorized error calling {}. All attempts to retry exhausted ", url);
                    throw e; 
                }
        }
        throw new ProgramException("Error while performing " + httpMethod + " request to " + url + ". " +
                "Response body: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e);
    }
}
```

Our catch of `HttpClientErrorException` is never hit; instead, we receive a `ResourceAccessException` with a cause of the above mentioned `IOException`.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Because you mention `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` but your config shows you using Apache HttpClient.